# flutter notification chat quick reply

Tags: flutter, dart

i have an application which is working fine. i add chatting to the app with notification. Any time users are chatting it send notification both in foreground and background.

**my question:**

how can i add notification reply just like `WhatsApp`. if a user send me message and i get the notification, i should be able to reply from the notification without opening the app.
[image]

Thanks

Comment: This isn't something you can do in Flutter alone. You will need to work in the native Android/iOS code in order to enable this feature. (Note that I'm not actually certain this is possible to do in iOS.)

Comment: @Abion47 okay can you give a resources of native, maybe i can try something out..

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this package: [Awesome Notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications). It is still under construction but it will enable you to display custom notifications including a `TextField` that you can show when a real Push Notification got received.